# Import module with argaprse and while using argparse in script

Tags: python, parsing

Im trying to import a module that contains argparse options to my main script. My main script also has argspars that need to pass a required argument. What is the best approach to do this?
here is an example:

## script_a

```
import argparse
import sys

def option():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-a', '--all', help="this is all")
    parser.add_argument('-b', '--other', help="this is other")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    return args

variable = "name"

def foo(variable):

    options = option()

    if options.all =='all':
        result = f"the result is all with {variable}"
 
    else:
        result = f"the result is other with {variable}"


    return result

def main():
    test = foo(variable)
    print(test)
```

Im importing my script1 to my main script, so basically merging the arguments together.

## main_script

```
import argparse
import sys
import scriptA

def option():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-i', '--info', help="Info.", required = True)
    arg = parser.parse_args()
    return arg


def main():
    scriptA.main()

    
if __name__ == "__main__":
     main()
```

I want to have the arguments for both script in the command line. like so,

```
python main_script.py -i info -a all
```

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23851239/add-argparse-arguments-from-external-modules